# How to use Amazon Java SDK with Maven on Glassfish?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, amazon-s3, glassfish

So in my POM I have

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.8</version>
</dependency>
```

And when I first create my client:

```
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(Config.AWS_CREDENTIALS);
```

I get an exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<clinit>(AmazonS3Client.java:193)
  at (my code)
  at (glassfish trace)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
  ... 48 more
```

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error states that you're missing commons logging dependency, add it into your maven file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

That should help.